# How to establish connection between jenkins and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, jenkins

I want to run a SQL query by using Jenkins Job or Pipeline. I don't know how to establish a connection between them.

If there is any change done in SQL file or stored procedure, then only the job should be run (like github auto commit).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer (but a suggestion) - 
When I googled, I got an only solution as installing a plugin called SQLCMD exe file. If it doesn't work for you try this below method (a work around idea from my side).

```
If you use Java - 

* Write a java program to connect to the Database and run select query / any queries.
* Make that java program as a jar file (which includes Oracle/SQL or any other dependency jars)
    * The program in java includes -
        * Connect DB
        * Fetch details (select / any query)
        * Write output to a text file (say output.txt)

* Write a shell script to run the Jar file (with command `java -jar GetDetailsFromDB.jar`)
    * The program in shell script includes -
        * Run java -jar (above) command
        * Read output.txt file 
        * echo/cat output.txt file in JenkinsConsole
```

It's easy to run shell script from Jenkisfile
**NB** : 
You might have to push the jar file (java program) to some artifactory or to GitHub so that to read from the jenkins.